# Magento 2 configurable product showing 0 price if we change locale to persian

Tags: product, configurable-product, price, magento-2.0.2

We are facing issue of product price in configurable product. At the time of loading product price is showing correct, once product is properly load then it is change to 0.00 for configurable product.

This issue happens with Magento 2 when we switch language. Also we have found this glitch with Magento 2.0.4 version by adding different language pack instead of Persian, still the same issue arise. And this issue arise in product detail page and not in product listing page.

Please find below image for more detailed clarification.

[image: Configurable product showing 0 price in Persian language]

Comment: Looks like magento2 is not implement the **SCP** feature yet! https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/335

Comment: did you tried refreshing cache after changing language?

Comment: This issue is not related to only configurable products. But for all type of products in product detail page. It is resetting price to 0.00 instead of actual price.